# Remove Tag from theme support

Tags: add-theme-support

I would remove Tag capability from classic Post type,
can I use `remove_theme_support( $feature );`  and how to do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `unregister_taxonomy('post_tag')` ?

Comment: @OneTrickPony Unfortunately [not yet](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11058)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with something like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse48017_remove_tags' );
function wpse48017_remove_tags() {
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    $tax = 'post_tag'; // this may be wrong, I never remember the names on the defaults
    if( taxonomy_exists( $tax ) )
        unset( $wp_taxonomies[$tax] );
}
```

There was a [move to get a function implemented](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11058) but that hasn't hit yet.

Answer (score 10):

As of WordPress 3.7, there is an `unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type` function available for just this sort of thing.

In your case:

```
// Remove tags support from posts
function myprefix_unregister_tags() {
    unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'post');
}
add_action('init', 'myprefix_unregister_tags');
```

View the documentation for this function [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/unregister_taxonomy_for_object_type/).

Comment: +1 but maybe you should check if the post type and the taxonomy are actually registered at this hook. And if they are, you probably don't want to use the same default priority of `10` as the callback to register it has used.

Comment: The chosen answer should be switched to this one.

Answer (score 0):

@m0r7if3r's answer actually produces an error in the in the 'Right Now' Dashboard widget.  Even with errors turned off, the 'Tags' row is displayed with a blank count.  I extended [that solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/48018/11957) to also hide 'Tags' from this Dashboard widget:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse48017_remove_tags' );
function wpse48017_remove_tags(){
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    unset($wp_taxonomies['post_tag']);
    global $pagenow;
    if( $pagenow == 'index.php' ){
        add_action( 'admin_head', 'ob_start', 0, 0 );
        add_action( 'right_now_content_table_end', 'wpse48017_remove_tags_dashboard' );
    }
}
function wpse48017_remove_tags_dashboard(){
    #echo '<pre>'.htmlentities( ob_get_clean(), 0, null, true );die();
    echo preg_replace('#(Categories</a></td></tr>)<tr>([\s\S]*?number_format\(\) expects parameter 1 to be double, object given[\s\S]*?)?<td class="first b b-tags.*?</tr>#','$1',ob_get_clean());
}
```

There are probably other areas where removing tags produces errors, or breaks hardcoded links.  So I thought of making this a community wiki, but that discussion probably belongs on [core.trac.wordpress.org](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11058).

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
function remove_unused_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'post_tag', // or any other taxonomy name e.g. 'category'
        array()
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_unused_taxonomies' );
```

It's not permanent, it will just hide taxonomy links in admin menu.