# How can I unregister a custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Problem: Homepage, tier 1, is able to load. Tier 2 pages always display the 404.php page.  Tier 3 pages (subpages of Tier 2) load perfectly.

Gathered Information:

1. functions.php - At the end of the functions.php file, the developer has registered a custom taxonomy called facebook-feeds.
2. I used a plugin called Rewrite Analyzer and i notice that it thinks my tier 2 pages are facebook-feeds for some reason.

I'm not quite sure how to fix this.

My first thought was to remove the registered taxonomy.  BUT I need a command or a function that will completely remove and make wordpress act like it never existed.

If there is a way to make it behave, that would be awesome too, but right now I'm getting some weirdness that I've never encountered before.

What do you suggest?

Comment: Take a look at this question. It removes the 'tag' support, you should be able to do the same with any other taxonomy. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48017/remove-tag-from-theme-support